# What is "Hammertime" a reference to?

Tags: terminology, divinity-original-sin

When the "knockdown" status effect is applied, text appears that says things like "whoops", "tripped", or "hammertime".

What does "hammertime" reference? I'm familiar with the M.C. Hammer song "Can't Touch This", but I don't recall there being anything about slipping and/or falling in it.

Comment: Stop!   Hammertime.

Comment: Kids these days. Next thing you know, they'll wonder what badgers have to do with mushrooms and snakes...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From the [status effect wikia page](http://divinity.wikia.com/wiki/Status_Effects_(Divinity:_Original_Sin)), the effect of Knockdown is:

> Cannot Move or Act

You have the reference right. It is a reference to the song ["Can't Touch This" by M.C. Hammer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otCpCn0l4Wo), as the lyric directly preceding "Hammertime" is "Stop!". Since the effect of Knockdown is the inability to move, you're effectively **stop**ped from moving.

Hammertime!

[image: can't touch this]

Comment: It is probably a good idea to indicate what *Stop! Hammertime!* is a reference to; as famous as MC Hammer was for that catchphrase, I’m sure there are people unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @KRyan I added a video ***and*** a gif for the reference! How's that?

Comment: Hah, fantastic.

Comment: Oh man I had almost forgotten that people actually wore those pants and did that dance.

Comment: Whole rest of my day ruined, by that stupid tune. Because literally everything that is better is less of an ear worm. Gah!

Answer (score -7):

The reference is to the In Living Color parody where MC Hammer gets lost in his pants while dancing.  Must see:

Comment: I very much doubt that. How would getting lost in your pants make sense as a reference here?

Comment: Obviously you weren't a teenager in the 80's.  Getting lost in the pants inhibits (or should) his movement. It's a sly throwback to this video.  Kind of like when someone says "Homey don't play that", it's from In Living Color.

Comment: No, I wasn't. But that doesn't change that this is just a parody of what Divinity: Original Sin is referencing. Based on YouTube views alone, it just wouldn't make sense to make an obscure reference like this. The original music video has 284m views, while the parody videos have at most 1.3m.